# Not printing duplicate values using view in entity model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I am using entity model.i updated one view called SalesDetialView.

In salesdetialview i have 3 entity keys. There are 1.Type 2.No, 3.Custmor
[image]

SQL : I am using this query(i am printing just 5 columns )

select Customer,Type,No,Salesperson,amount from SalesDetailView 
[image]

But through entity model i am not getting duplicate values(No).see this below screen [image]

Now i have doubt why it is not showing duplicate values. Any thing related for entity keys  or any thing. Please suggest me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: What query does EF emit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If multiple rows share the same value in the primary column(s), only the first of these seems to be retrieved from the database and copied into these other rows. For instance, if a set has 2 columns, with the first being marked as the primary column, and

```
the correct result should be:

A, 1
A, 2
B, 4
B, 6
B, 7
C, 5


The actual result in code with Entity Framework would become:


A, 1
A, 1
B, 4
B, 4
B, 4
C, 5
```

When including a view in your Entity Model, the model seems to simply use the first not-nullable columns as primary key (as all columns used in the primary key should be non-nullable).
To fix the problem, make sure that the primary key columns are chosen correctly. If you cannot create the correct primary key because of null-values or simply not having set of columns that differs for each row, try adding a column to your view that always contains a unique value for each row. After you add it, make sure it is set as the primary key in your Entity Model.

If I would set both rows to be the Primary Columns in the above example, I would get the desired result.

Comment: using primary column we are not showing duplicates. But in my view it does not have pk columns in it. when run the quary in sql it is showing all rows. But not through entity model.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it by changing the merge option of the `ObjectSet`. Example:

```
 using (TargetDBDataContext db = new TargetDBDataContext())
        {
            db.SomeView.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
            return db. SomeView.ToList();
        }
```